# Add new file on eclipse only accepting new projects

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to eclipse and was messing around with some settings. I go to add a file and it allows me to select a new project or import an existing project. This has never been an issue before.
[the only options allowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXAgP.png)

Comment: Other... should open the full dialog of options.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which entries are displayed in the _New_ menu before _Other..._ depends on the current perspective. It doesn't look like you're in the Java perspective.